# Not Able to Start Hadoop Service Locally On Windows 7

Tags: hadoop, port

I am trying to set up hadoop locally on my windows 7 computer by the instructions on the following link:
https://dimensionless.in/know-how-to-install-and-run-hadoop-on-windows-for-beginners/

I followed each single step and hadoop looks to be properly installed as I checked it by running this command: hadoop version in the windows command prompt and it returned the installed hadoop version hadoop 3.1.0 successfully.

However it failed to start all the nodes e.g. namenode, data node, yarn. I realised it must be to do with the port used as I use local port 9000 in the core site configuration: hdfs://localhost:9000 , and I checked if the port is open by running command: telnet localhost 9000, and it returned the message that failed to open the port.

Can anyone provide any guidance on the above issue which looks to be the port issue which then failed the hadoop service from starting up?

Thank you.

Comment: There is a log file for things that don't start...

Comment: the logs folder contains no log though for some reason.

Comment: Even when I ran the command hadoop fs -ls , it threw out the following message: WARN: util.NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop ls: Call from mydesktop-PC/xxx.xxx.x.x to localhost:9000 failed on connection exception: java.net.ConnectException:Connection refused: no further information. For more details see: http://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/ConnectionRefused

Comment: And did you read that link? Which logs folder did you open?

Comment: Yes, I read the link from apache org, however it did not help. I opened the logs folder in the %HADOOP_HOME%/logs folder I set up on my computer.

Comment: So, my advice would be to use the existing Hortonworks/Cloudera quickstart VMs. I strongly advice people not to run Hadoop on Windows. Especially not Windows 7 because its EOL

Comment: yes, I have given up trying to run hadoop on my local computer. I am now signing up to a free Azure Account and try hadoop from azure HDInsight.